# How to export data as it appears in the cell rather than its real value

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

When you export from excel using "save as" as a csv the values save in the csv as they appear in the cell. For example in this spreadsheet a cell shows the value "0:01:22" in it. When I save and export this using Microsoft excel the value appears as "0:01:22" in the csv. However when I use pandas and export it to csv it appears in the csv as "0:01:22.25000".

My guess is that the real value of the cell is actually the latter but when you export it using excel vs pandas, excel can keep the formatting where as pandas can only get the raw data.

Right now I have to use pandas, and then change the values in the dataframe to match the expected formatting for my program before exporting. My question is: Is there a way to do this using python that keeps the formatting? If so how do I do it?

Some extra information:

- I am coding on macOS. I know there may be a solution using pywin32 but this is for windows and nothing I found that states I can use this with macOS.
- I cannot change the spreadsheet in anyway. The spreadsheets are out of my control and I can't change any settings or formatting to do with them.
- I would rather only export using python and its' packages only, however if there is an elegant solution using another method I would happily hear it.

The code I am using to export from the excel sheet:

```
@staticmethod
    def excel_sheet_to_csv(path_to_excel_file, sheet_name):
        data_xlsx = pd.read_excel(path_to_excel_file, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        data_xlsx.to_csv(f'resources/{sheet_name}.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: I don't believe this. CSV is a text format what you see is what  you get. I don't see how  `0:01:22` can go from CSV to Pandas and then come out of Pandas to end up in CSV as `0:01:22.25000` without some additional process in Pandas changing the value.

Comment: Im talking about excel file to dataframe to csv. The number change comes from the excel file to dataframe not the csv to dataframe.